# Exception while retrieving related entities

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have a problem getting related entities from CRM.

The following code:

```
var conn = CrmConnection.Parse("my connection string");
var orgService = new OrganizationService(conn);
var context = new MyServiceContext(orgService);

...
var myEntity = context.CreateQuery<new_myentity>().First(p => p.new_name == "some name");
myEntity.GetRelatedEntities(context, "relation name").ToList();
```

throws the following Exception in hte last line:

> The value 'Microsoft.Xrm.Client.Configuration.CrmConfigurationProvider, Microsoft.Xrm.Client' is not recognized as a valid type or is not of the type 'Microsoft.Xrm.Client.Configuration.CrmConfigurationProvider'.

Comment: Sounds like you're missing a reference. http://dotnetinside.com/en/type/Microsoft.Xrm.Client/CrmConfigurationManager/6.0.0.0

Comment: I do have reference to Microsoft.Xrm.Client.dll

Comment: I'm pretty sure we ran into similar errors and the only solution was to install the referenced DLLs into the GAC (on the machine[s] running the SSIS packages).

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try...I can't test because I don't have an early-bound class DLL on this machine, but I think this may do the trick. Please let me know.

```
CrmConnection connection = CrmConnection.Parse("my connection string");
 
var proxy = new Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceProxy(
connection.ServiceUri,
connection.HomeRealmUri,
connection.ClientCredentials,
connection.DeviceCredentials);
 
proxy.EnableProxyTypes();

IOrganizationService service = (IOrganizationService)proxy; 
var context = new CrmOrganizationServiceContext(service);   

var myEntity = context.CreateQuery<Entity>().First(p => p.new_name == "some name");
myEntity.GetRelatedEntities(context, "relation name").ToList();
```

Comment: nope, same issue. Maybe I should have mentioned I'm running this inside a SSIS package script task if this makes any difference

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue when using the CRM SDK to get related entities from within an SSIS custom component.

You can also get this error from say a console app if you don't set "Copy Local" to true in the referenced assembly's properties in VS for the microsoft.xrm.client assembly.

For SSIS, to resolve that error you need to copy the microsoft.xrm.client assembly to the:
{DriveLetter}:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn directory (or {DriveLetter}:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn if applicable).